# Sum of squares of harmonic functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, laplacian, maximum-principle

I have to show $w(x)=\sum_ju_j^2(x)$ has its maximum value on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. The functions $u_j$'s are all harmonic. I think I need to show that $w$ is also harmonic and then I can use the maximum principle to complete the proof. I know that the sum of harmonic functions is also harmonic. Is there a way to show that the square of a harmonic function is also harmonic? Or am I thinking completely in the wrong direction?

Comment: The square is not harmonic, but subharmonic, which you can show by using the Jensen's inequality. By this property with a similar arguement as in the harmonic case you can show that a subharmonic function achieves its maximum at the boundary.

Comment: Also the sum of subharmonic functions is subharmonic.